# Display HTML special characters in JSP: Why and When they are being escaped?

Tags: java, html, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a file testHTML.jsp to display a string which contains some HTML special characters:

```
<body>
    <div id="test" class="test">
        <c:out value="${htmlContent}" />
    </div>
</body>
```

Variable htmlContent is set in a SpringMVC controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/testHTML", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getHTML(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String content = "<html>\n<p>Test Me\n</html>\n";
    request.setAttribute("htmlContent", content);
    return "/test/testHTML";
}
```

Deploy the test app on Tomcat and use Firefox to display the jsp. The variable content is printed in its original format with angle brackets, etc. That is, the HTML special characters are escaped. This could be confirmed by viewing the source code of the rendered page of Firefox.

My question is who did the escape job during this process? The web browser (Firefox), the jsp engine, or something else? Thanks

Comment: FF wouldn't. it has **NO** idea what's running on the server. it only sees the output of the server-side code. That output could be produced by java, php, a shell script, or an army of monkeys banging on keyboards. firefox doesn't care, and doesn't need to care.

Comment: It is the `escapeXml` attribute associated with the JSTL `<c:out>` tag whose default value is true. You may explicitly set it to false, if needed in any case. This has whatsoever nothing to do with Spring/Spring MVC/any browsers.

Comment: If Firefox is not involved in, then who did the job? It's a small test application with a jsp at front end, SpringMVC as the controller and purely with Java.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see Tiny's comment. Thanks Tiny.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to define the content in standard template. To make it cross browser compatible.

```
String content ="
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Test Me</h1>

<p>Test Me 2.</p>

</body>
</html>";
```